# Retrieving values for which ID has no value in a joint table for a specific column value

Tags: mysql

I know, this question title isn't appealing, but it's quite tricky to explain in one sentence, so here's what I have in my 2 tables.

```
Table 1

ID    other_id
1     1
2     1
3     2

Table 2
ID    parent_id    attribute_id    value
54    1            125             jiazdjdaz
55    1            367             5
58    2            125             zdvgbdajz
59    2            367             4
71    3            125             hagvbadd
```

t2.parent_id is equal to t1.ID

I want to be able to retrieve "other_id" 2, because it has no value in table T2, for attribute 367.

How can I easily do that?

Comment: You can easily try something. And we can easily comment on that.

Comment: I forgot how easily people were bitching on SO. If I knew how to do it or what to look for on the web, do you think I'd be asking questions here?

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more. "I want to be able to retrieve "other_id" 2, because it has no value in table T2, for attribute 367." sound little confusing.

Comment: @JaseemAbbas I understand the confusion. I'd like to get all the rows from t1, where t2 (joint table) has no value for `t2.attribute_id=367`. In this case we'd retrieve T1's last row, for T2 doesn't have a row where `t2.parent_id=3` and `t2.attribute_id=367`

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry You Sir, are persistent. I have provided an example of my DB Tables, and was unable to provide a query example as I didn't know what I was looking for. What I tried was joining my second table to looking for `NULL` values where a certain `attribute_id` had a specific value. Of course it yielded no result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is known as *existential quantification*, a test for existence.  In SQL, use `EXISTS`.

```
select other_id from T1 
where not exists ( 
    select 1 from T2 
    where T1.ID = T2.parent_id
    and attribute_id = 367
)
```

There's more than one way to do it.  You'll also see solutions on the web that use an outer join, testing for NULL on the inner table.  And you'll find allegations that correlated subqueries like that are slow, which depends on the DBMS.  Hopefully this at least gives you a starting point.

Comment: I had never seen `where not exists` before. Thanks for the insight, it's exactly what I needed. Now I can build a proper query.